# Does it matter how a link from the 'share' dialog is opened?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, sharing

The *Announcer* badge is given for:

- *Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses..*

If the user right-clicks on the link and selects *Open link in new Tab* to visit the link, is that counted as a visit or not?

Comment: No. It isn't... Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238069/how-do-you-guys-count-question-views-now

Comment: @PatrickHofman: that's how the 'viewed' counter is calculated. The *badges* count unique IP addresses, so only one view per IP address counts towards the badge.

Comment: my question is that is it calculated as a unique one if opens in a new tab?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're right. Missed that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A visit is a visit is a visit.

If a user opens your link in a new tab, in a new window, or types it in by hand, character by character, in the browser of their mobile phone, then they are all visiting the shared link. It *doesn't matter how the link was opened*.

As long as you use the `share` link on the question, each visit from a unique IP address counts toward the link. These links contain your userid in the form `/q/<question_id>/<user_id>` for questions, and `/a/<answer_id>/<user_id>` for answers.

Comment: I think OP doesn't know how the link is tracked, so some clarification: the link you get from the *share* dialog contains your user ID.

Comment: @Stijn: expanded on that.